# Searching a JSON formatted array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to search the below array which is in JSON format.

```
[{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"}, 
{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}]
```

I want to first check the first element in this case "SystemID" and append all the values of "SystemID" to op1 array I have created. I am not sure how to do this, my code to search the array is below (JS file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            op1 = [];

            if (data[i] == 'SystemID') {
                for(var i in data) {
                    op1.push(data[i]['SystemID'])
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

When I run this code now, op1 is empty.

I want op1 to have all the values of SystemID from the JSON array.

UPDATE: I want to check IF the element is "SystemID" and if so, appened the first element to "op1". The first element and second element in my JSON data could change, so I want to check that first and then append the first element to "op1". Also I want to check the second element, and append the second elements value to "op2" array.

Comment: What is data[i]?? what does i refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like that , you are missing the `for` loop

```js
var data = [{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"}, 
{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}]

    var op1 = [];
    var op2 = [];
    for(let i=0; i < data.length;i++){
      for(let item in data[i]){
         if(item == "SystemID"){
           op1.push(data[i][item])
         }
         if(item == "ApparentPower"){
           op2.push(data[i][item])
         }
      }
    }


console.log(op1)
console.log(op2)
```

if you wanna use ECMA6

```js
 let data = [{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}]

        let op1 = data.map(item => item.SystemID);
        let op2 = data.map(item => item.ApparentPower);
      
    console.log(op1)
    console.log(op2)
```

if you wanna global concept

```js
 let data = [{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}]


let data_keys = Object.keys(data[0])
let result = []
for(let item in data_keys){
  result.push([])
}
  for(let i=0; i < data.length;i++){
    for(key in data_keys){
      if(Object.keys(data[i])[key] == data_keys[key]){
        result[key].push(Object.values(data[i])[key])
      }
    }
  }



for(let k=0; k<result.length;k++){
console.log(result[k])
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I have tried this, it's working. So if the first element was e.g. "Datarecorded" , would I add another if statement and compare against that element and push the data of that in op1 instead? Thanks

Comment: @Danny yup, if you want them in different arrays

Comment: I need to create another for loop like the above and create a similar condition for another array to store the second element, yes?

Comment: Ok I'm abit confused. Let's say if Apparent Power (AP) was the first element and SystemID (SID) was the second, would AP be appended to op1 still? I need the first element to always be appended to op1 and second to op2 (Sorry if I was unclear)

Comment: it's based on your checks , what exactly you wanna do @Danny ?

Comment: I want to what the first element is, and append all the values of the first element to "op1", and I want to check what the second element is and append all the values of the second element to "op2". My first and second element may change in JSON data so therefore want to check what is in the both elements.

Comment: @Danny, i have updated the answer with global concept

Comment: Okay nice, how do I append the first element values to op1 and the second elements values to op2 in your code? I appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: `result` is an array of arrays

Comment: How exactly would I grab the first elements and push to op1? and the second elements to op2? As they are all in "result"

Comment: I need two separate arrays, the first elements in op1 and second in op2

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want all the `SystemID` in the array `op1`:

```js
const data = [{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}];
const op1 = data.map(item => item.SystemID);

console.log(op1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your code will be like this

```js
 var json = [{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
     {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
     {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"}, 
    {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}];


     var myArray =[];

       json.forEach(function (item) { 
          if(item.SystemID) {
                myArray.push(item.SystemID);
           }
       });

       console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the first key in particular is SystemID ? if that's the case you could try

```js
const data = [
  {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
  {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"}, 
  {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"}, 
  {"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}, 
  {"NOTASystemID":"6sss","ApparentPower":"796"}
];

const op = data
  .filter(element => Object.keys(element)[0]==="SystemID") //filtering out element with first key sysID
  .map(element => element.SystemID);

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already parsed the JSON data, you can just map through the array and use the [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to check if each object in the array has `SystemID` or not and if it does, push it's value to the `op1` array.

*Trying to retrieve elements in an object using index is not reliable since object properties are unsorted.*

```js
var data = [{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}];

var op1 = data.map(e => {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty("SystemID")) {
    return e.SystemID;
  } else {
    // do something else since current mapped object doesn't have "SystemID"
  }
});

console.log(op1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
var data = '[{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"822"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"807"},{"SystemID":"62750003","ApparentPower":"796"}]';

 var op1 = [];
 $.each(JSON.parse(data),function(i,item){
   op1[i] = item.SystemID;
 });
 console.log(op1);
```